# unstyled list drops text in next row. how to stop this?

Tags: html, list, bootstrap-5

I'm about to build a simple menu card with bootstrap. I'm not a dev pro so I've decided to list them with unstyled list. I also defined span with float: right that the price is always right aligned. Problem now is that when I resize my browser to view output for different devices, the price drops into the next row when the column is too tight. How to avoid this?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li>rashcook omlette +khobz*<span><u>8.5€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+rinderschinken<span><u>3.5€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+avocado-minze<span><u>3€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+tomaten-salsa<span><u>2.5€</u></span></li>
              </ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define behavior for different screen sizes with bootstrap using `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl` and `xxl`.
To cause a newline in this case, you can force the `<u>` element to display as `block` instead of `inline` on screens smaller than `sm` (576px by default).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="width: 300px">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>rashcook omlette +khobz*<u class="d-block d-sm-inline float-sm-end">8.5€</u></li>
    <li class="ps-2">+rinderschinken<u class="d-block d-sm-inline float-sm-end">3.5€</u></li>
    <li class="ps-2">+avocado-minze<u class="d-block d-sm-inline float-sm-end">3€</u></li>
    <li class="ps-2">+tomaten-salsa<u class="d-block d-sm-inline float-sm-end">2.5€</u></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

*I replaced the padding by `0.5rem` (8px) with the class `ps-2`.*

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">rashcook omlette +khobz*<span><u>8.5€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+rinderschinken<span><u>3.5€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+avocado-minze<span><u>3€</u></span></li>
                <li style="padding-left: 10px;">+tomaten-salsa<span><u>2.5€</u></span></li>
              </ul>
```

can you try like this? If not, I suggest you look at bootstrap grid.

Comment: Would be useful to explain what you changed and why.

Comment: style is not applied to the first li tag.

Comment: would be useful to make this part of your answer. Although looking at the question, I dont think the first item is supossed to have padding.

Comment: That's correct. Padding was not supposed for first item.